# Azure DevOps Pipeline - Unable to see artifacts with failed build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Azure DevOps pipelines changed recently and now I don't see a way to download artifact when a build fails - we have log files that are saved.  Where can I see the artifacts?

Usually it was in the drop down on the right:

[image: Azure devops pipeline details]

It shows very clearly that it uploads an artifact in the log file:

[image: publish artifacts in pipeline log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to open in the `Artifacts (1 published)` section:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

OMG. I have been looking for this link for an hour. Its doesn't even say artefacts any more - its just a tiny icon which you are supposed to know is a link to the files. Microsoft please hire a new UX designer to fix this. The documentation or lack of it is shocking.

Comment: Correct. The UX in insane for the artifacts. On the top-right there is a menu accessible by clicking on 3 vertical dots: we can download the logs from there, but NOT the artifacts. So confusing!